# Notation: Functions of Derivatives of Variables

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, notation

I'm sorry if this has been asked before and if the title is unclear; I'm not sure how to search for this question. Is it proper to write a function that is a function it's variables derivative as:

$$f(x)=\frac{dx}{dt}=\dot{x}$$

instead of

$$f(\dot{x})=\dot{x}$$

where $x=x(t)$? This (possibly) creates a contradiction in that

$$f(x)=f(\dot{x})$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what is your question; people write $\dot{x} = f(x)$ informally to mean the differential equation $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))$ for all $t$ on some domain.

Comment: That's a good point. Here's an example. If I'm trying to define the force $f$ due to friction, I would say something like $f(\dot{x})=-k\dot{x}$. But I could also write $f(x)=-k\frac{dx}{dt}=-k\dot{x}$ couldn't I?

Comment: Well, the two equations you've written are different. The first takes $\dot{x}$ as the parameter, the second $x$. I think you probably mean the second equation. (Yes, you can write the second equation, here $f$ is a function of functions $x$ and you apply the differential operator on the right which is in itself a function.)

Comment: @QiZhu, I see what you're saying. Would you agree that both $f(\dot{x})=-k\dot{x}$ and $f(x)=-k\frac{dx}{dt}$ are acceptable ways to write it, but maybe the second way is canonical?

Comment: No, I‘m saying that these two mean different things.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not tracking. What is wrong with writing the following? $f(\dot{x})=-k\dot{x}=-k\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$

Comment: If you set $f(x) = \dot{x}$, then $f(\dot{x}) = x’’$. You‘re plugging in the function $\dot{x}$ after all - and not $x$ itself in $f(\dot{x})$.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. So the problem is $f$ cannot be a function of just $x$ and just $\dot{x}$ (as  you stated previously). So the above should be written $f(\dot{x})=-k\dot{x}=-k\frac{dx}{dt}=g(x)$, where $f$ and $g$ are different functions.

Comment: Yes. A function has a domain and a codomain - so here one natural domain to take is the space of differentiable function e.g.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine a function that is a function of its own derivative. Sounds like a circular reference.

Perhaps you mean this. Consider a function $x = x(t)$ and you can have a function of both $x(t)$ and $x'(t)$ at the same time? For example, consider an iteration of Newton's method, which computes
$$
N(t, x(t), x'(t)) = t - \frac{x(t)}{x'(t)}.
$$
This is well-defined as a map $N : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$.

If you want to map functions to other functions, it's a different story. For example, consider the space $\mathcal{S}$ of all one-variable functions, differentiable infinitely many times on $[0,1]$, e.g. $\cos(x)$ or $e^x$ or any polynomial. Then you can have a map $D : \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{S}$ defined by
$$
D[f(x)] = f'(x),
$$
thus mapping $e^x \to e^x$ and $\sin x \to \cos x$, for example.

Comment: I think I meant "function that is a function of its variables derivative". Overall, I think what I'm asking is if it makes sense to write $f(x)=\dot{x}$. From your answer, it sounds like no, but I'm not quit sure why.